# Split dynamic char into N sized chunks C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a long dynamic char that I am trying to split into chunks of 20 characters max. The code below is what I have so far. The issue I am facing is it seems to work in the "`for loop calculations`" section, but when I then read out the results again in the "`Checking results`" they all seem to be set to the last output from the first section.

```
  char* largeWord = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff";

  char* chunks[] = {
    "will be overridden"
  };

  int index = 0;
  const int blockSize = 20;

  Serial.println("=== for loop calculations ===");
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(largeWord); i += blockSize ) {

    char buff[blockSize];
    memcpy(buff, &largeWord[i], blockSize);
    chunks[index++] = buff;

    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(buff);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.println();
  }

  Serial.println("=== Checking results ===");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(chunks[i]);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.println();
  }
```

The output from this is:

```
=== for loop calculations ===
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa⸮!"
"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb⸮!"
"cccccccccccccccccccc⸮!"
"dddddddddddddddddddd⸮!"
"eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee⸮!"
"fffffffffffffffffff"
=== Checking results ===
0"fffffffffffffffffff"
1"fffffffffffffffffff"
2"fffffffffffffffffff"
3"fffffffffffffffffff"
4"fffffffffffffffffff"
```

As you can see from the output, the "`for loop calculations`" is what is it calculating and what I am expecting, but all I am getting is the '`fffff...`' output instead. How should I go about fixing this?

(Also on a side note, there is also "⸮!" appearing, so I guess I am doing something wrong with memory allocation?)

Update:

I have attempted to update my code and fix the issue of it accessing an out of bounds index with the following code:

```
  char* largeWord = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff";

  char chunks[6][20] = {};

  int index = 0;
  const int blockSize = 20;

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(largeWord); i += blockSize ) {
    memcpy(chunks[index++], &largeWord[i], blockSize);
  }

  Serial.println("=== Checking results ===");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(chunks[i]);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.println();
  }
```

Which seems to be getting closer to the result I want as the output is now:

```
=== Checking results ===
0"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff"
1"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff"
2"ccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff"
3"ddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff"
4"eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff"
```

So it seems like memcpy was not limiting it to 20 like its meant to. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `chunks` is an array of one element; `chunks[0]` is the only valid index into it. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Plus, you populate `chunks` with an address of a local variable, that is created and destroyed every time through the first loop, and doesn't exist outside of that loop. By the time you access the pointers in the second loop, they are dangling - not pointing to any valid object.

Comment: Thanks for the response @IgorTandetnik , I have updated my code, I seem to be getting closer, but not quite there yet. Any feedback?

Comment: @jLynx - your compiler may be outsmarting you. If compiling with `gcc` (e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc`), try compiling with `-O1` or `-O0` as the optimization level. If using an IDE, find where compiler optimizations can be turned off. (most compiler setups not default to `-O2` optimization). While you only have 19 `'f'` characters `largeWord` is *nul-terminated*, so you actually have a 20th character. So `memcpy()` doesn't access outside your array. But gcc compiles (at least from Ver. 7.4 on) play a bit fast and loose with string optimizations. (even though you copy chars)

Comment: Serial.print expects a C string, which is a char array terminated by 0. you are missing the terminating 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue of your code as below

```
char* largeWord = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffff";

  char* chunks[6];

  int index = 0;
  const int blockSize = 20;

  Serial.println("=== for loop calculations ===");
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(largeWord); i += blockSize ) {

      char* buff=new char[blockSize+1];
    memcpy(buff, &largeWord[i], blockSize);
    buff[blockSize] = '\0';
    chunks[index++] = buff;

    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(buff);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.println();
  }

  Serial.println("=== Checking results ===");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(chunks[i]);
    Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.println();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have have Arduino installed on my machine to write the code

I believe the problem you have is that when you print chunks[i], it read until it reaches a null terminator character `'\0'`.

Because in C and C++ strings are null terminated, or you can say it as a string is a char array ending with a null value, and so many functions in C/C++ rely on null terminated strings to know when to stop reading, so you should add null terminator as delimiter between each 20 bytes(characters)  so if you choose this method you will also need to change the blockSize to 21 instead of 20

or use substring() [Documentation here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/substring/) use the following syntax :

> myString.substring(from, to)

`from` will be your offset and set `to` to the number of characters you want to read and note also if you choose this approach you don't have to split the string, unless you have another reason to do so.